# Stochastic Matrix: Second largest eigenvalue and second largest absolute value of eigen value

Tags: computational-complexity, matrices, eigenvector, inequalities

### Setup

Let $A$ be a stochastic matrix.

Let the eigenvalues of $A$ be $1 = \lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \lambda_3 ... \geq -1$.

Let $\lambda = \max_{x: x \perp 1} \frac{||Ax||}{|| x ||}$

### Question:

Besides $\lambda_2 \leq \lambda$, is there any relation between $\lambda$ and $\lambda_2$? In particular, I would love to see something of the form $\lambda \leq \lambda_2$.

### Context:

Reading about expanders. Many of the proofs appears to prove upper bounds on $\lambda_2$, but I want upper bounds on $\lambda$, and it's not obvious to me:

(1) how an upper bound on $\lambda_2$ becomes an upper bound on $\lambda$
or
(2) how to generalize some of these proofs.

Thanks!

Comment: I think some stochastic matrices have complex eigenvalues; so are you assuming some other conditions on $A$ at the start? (These might be relevant if you are trying to get relations between $\lambda$ and $\lambda_2$.)

Comment: Note that if $\bf v$ is an eigenvector for any eigenvalue other than 1 then $\bf v$ is orthogonal to the all-ones vector. 

Answer (score 5):

The answer is due to Boyd, Diaconis, Sun & Xiao. If $A$ is a symmetric and bi-stochastic, then $\mu:=\max(\lambda_2,-\lambda_n)$ satisfies
$$\mu\ge\cos\frac\pi{n}.$$
In addition, there exists such a matrix for which the equality holds. See Exercise 164 of my list http:\www.umpa.ens-lyon.fr/~serre/DPF/exobis.pdf .

**P.S.** Because you assume that the eigenvalues are real, I presume that you have in mind that the matrix is symmetric.

Comment: But it is possible for the eigenvalues to be real even if the matrix is not symmetric, so I'm not sure why you make that assumption. 

Comment: just because I don't know how to explain that of the author: the eigenvalues are real.